Elementor Forms API - Set different headers for Email 1 and Email 2
I am currently trying to dynamically add CC email addresses to an Elementor form's email through the WordPress functions.php file. My client wants me to only add the CC email addresses when a specific value from a drop down / select field is selected. I've managed to get it to work but now it adds those CC email addresses to both emails. (Reference: Add CC or BCC email addresses dynamically when submitting a Elementor form, through the WordPress functions.php file)
I use the Elementor Form Actions After Submit Emails in the following ways:

Email = supplied information is send to the website owner
Email 2 = a copy of the supplied informi s send to the visitor who filled out the form

Here is the code:
##############################################################################
// Action is called when the forms is submitted and being processed
##############################################################################
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/process', 'add_cc_emails_to_submitted_elementor_forms', 10, 2 );
function add_cc_emails_to_submitted_elementor_forms( $record, $handler ) {
    // Get the form name
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );
    
    // Check which form is being processed
    if ( $form_name !== 'FORM NAME') {
        return;
    }

    // Create an array of all the fields used in the form
    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
    
    // Get the selected drop down value
    $drop_down_field_value = $raw_fields['field_name']['value'];
    
    // Set the CC email addresses
    if( $drop_down_field_value === 'SOMETHING' ){   
        // Call the filter to apply the needed CC Emails
        add_filter( 'elementor_pro/forms/wp_mail_headers', 'add_cc_emails_to_elementor_form', 10, 1 );
    }
}

##############################################################################
// Add CC email addresses to the Email Header
##############################################################################
function add_cc_emails_to_elementor_form( $headers ) {
    
    // Set all the CC email addresses   
    $headers .= "Cc: something@email.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Cc: something2@email.com\r\n";
    
    return $headers;
}

Is there a way for me to set the headers based on the email that is being send. I only need the CC email addresses added to Email 1 (the one that gets send to the website owner) and not Email 2. The information on the developer docs (https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/forms/) don't mention anything about it.
